# Watch tomcat log file in Windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, catalina.out

When I was working on Ubuntu, I used the following command to watch changes on `catalina.out` :

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

But now I changed to Windows, and I can't find how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/68703/windows-xp-equivalent-of-tail-f)

Answer (score 4):

You have several options:

1. Install Cygwin, Mingw64 or GNU Utilities and you will have "tail"
   command
2. Use PowerShell and something like:
   `Get-Content catalina.out -Wait`
3. Use external tool like Notepad++: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/monitor-log-or-text-file-changes-in-real-time-with-notepad/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Notepad++. You can find the setting in Settings -> Preferences... -> MISC -> File Status Auto-Detection. Check all three boxes and the files will be updated on change and scrolled to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the editors like TextPad shows signal when there is any change in the  file you opened through this tool. You can open your log using some of those editors and whenever Tomcat update the logs you can fetch the changes.